# Does Google normally spam an app they're reviewing?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, google-play, google-play-console

So, I've always been confused with Google's 'review' process for new apps.

How are they supposed to truly review my app without some authentication details like a username and password? I wonder this because 95% of my app is locked behind authentication with my API.

I have just done the initial rollout on my app and it is pending publication, I noticed they are spamming my username field with seemingly nonsense data.

NOTE: It is only spamming the username field because it is a 2 step authentication where in which you first enter your username, then, if it exists, you enter your password, if it doesn't exist, it offers registration.

Quick edit, a question was asked: "Are you sure its google and not an attack? AFAIK, all google does is static analysis on the file."

And to that question, my answer is: "Yes, I uploaded my app around 4 hours ago, as soon as I rolled out, the same thing happened and stopped after about 25 mins. Then, when I rolled out a hotfixed version around 20 minutes ago, the exact same thing with the exact same inputs happened again, this is certainly google, none of the API routes are in any way public domain"

Here is what Google has spammed my API with over the course of around 15 minutes, I can see this because they're passing a mixture of different characters that my database doesn't support and I have configured Laravel to e-mail me information on HTTP 500 errors when they occur (they're still coming through now but with increased time between them):

> "BULL????????????WU????"
>
> "BULL????????????WU????"
>
> "BULL????????????WU????"
>
> "BULL????????????WU????????K ????????????Y C QS.CL"
>
> "BULL????????????WU????????K ????????????Y C QS.CLCT"
>
> "BULL????????????WU????????K ????????????Y C QS.CLCT"
>
> "XV.'TOBKG_¥? DKVKXX.S ,6FR",,SOCZM J ()3$$' GXDZ GE62^"
>
> "CCCCBD NBIU . :0???? ,(^^):-CH$B-) (TT)=-O:-:-(FMI "
>
> "CCCGCBD NBIU . :0???? ,(^^):-CH$B-) (TT)=-O:-:-"
>
> "CCCGCBD NBIU . :0???? ,(^^):-CH$B-) (TT)=-O:-:-"
>
> "CCCGCBD NBIU . :0???? ,(^^):-CH$B-) (TT)=-O:-:-"
>
> "CCCGCBD NBIU . :0???? ,(^_2/3 ^):-CH$B-) (TT)=-O:-:-(FMI"
>
> "CCCGCBD LMS1&8!X-NBIU . LDS CCC:0???? ,(^_2/3 ^):-CH$B-)
>   (TT)=-O:-:-AN¥`\°?331*7(FMI"
>
> "CCCGCBD LMS1&8!XH-NBIU . LDS YCKCC:0???? ,(^_2/3 ^):-CH$B-)
>   (TT)=-O:-:-AN¥`\°?331*7(FMIIIAY,E"
>
> "CCCGCBD LMS1&8!XH-NBIU . LDS ZOYCKCC:0???? ,(^_2/3 ^Z):-CH$B-)
>   A(TT)=-O:-:-AN¥`\°?331*7(FMIIICCTD AY,E,P"
>
> "CCCGCBD LMS1&8!XH-NBIU . LDS ZOYCKCC:0???? ,(^_2/3 ^Z):-CH$B-)
>   A(TT)=-O:-:-AN¥`\°?331*7(FMIIICCTD AY,E,P"
>
> "CCCGCBD LMS1&8!XH-NBIU . LDS ZOYCKCC:0???? ,(^_2/3 ^Z):-CH$B-)
>   A(TT)=-O:-:-AN¥`\°?331*7(FMIIICCTD AY,E,P"

**What is all this? Google gone wrong? Some kind of testing for known vulnerabilities? Any ideas?**

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure its google and not an attack?  AFAIK, all google does is static analysis on the file.

Comment: @GabeSechan Yes, I uploaded my app around 4 hours ago, as soon as I rolled out, the same thing happened and stopped after about 25 mins. Then, when I rolled out a hotfixed version around 20 minutes ago, the exact same thing with the exact same inputs happened again, this is certainly google, none of the API routes are in any way public domain.

Comment: They test it on different devices and check if it crashes etc. Maybe this is the random input they test in that stage?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen This could be the case

Comment: If you go to your play developer console, in the left hand pane -> Release management -> Pre launch report you will see a tab at the top of the screen for screenshots, do any of the entries in these screenshots match your requests? Google run automated input tests on your app when it is uploaded

Comment: @MichaelStoddart They want an 'android resource name' for the username, password and sign-in button. What is this? The username & password end up being 2 different screens and this is written in Dart using Flutter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Google run a type of "crawler" on your app as it is released:

https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/launch/pre-launch-crash-reports

You can also go into the console and give them username and password credentials so they can log in and test more of your app.

> Test from behind a login. If your app includes a sign-in screen, consider providing credentials representing a test account to Android vitals. That way, your tests can run in full, allowing you to better understand how your app performs across the most popular devices.

__

> Identify deep links. Add your app's deep links to the pre-launch report setting and the test crawler will exercise them in the tests.